# How to resolve dependency using wild card while generating pom.xml from gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle

I am using Gradle (v2.0) in my application. For one of the dependencies I am using wild card in the version (see the code below)

**build.gradle**

```
ext {
  my_utils_version = "1.0+"
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.demo.myapp:my-utils:${my_utils_version}"
}
```

I am generating POM from my gradle build using following piece of code

```
task writePom << {
  conf2ScopeMappings.mappings.remove(configurations.testCompile)
  conf2ScopeMappings.mappings.remove(configurations.testRuntime)
  pom {
  }.writeTo("$buildDir/libs/pom.xml")
}
assemble.dependsOn writePom
```

So, whenever Gradle generates the POM, it uses `1.0+` as the version for the dependency `compile "com.demo.myapp:my-utils:${my_utils_version}"`. In the generated POM.xml, I see

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.demo.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0+</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maven is not able to resolve version `1.0+`. Maven requires `[1.0)` as its own wildcard versioning.

Could someone help me in resolving this issue? How can I tell Gradle to use `[1.0)` instead of  `1.0+`?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle does support Maven's version range notation, so you can use `[1.0)` in the build script (although I'm not quite sure if Maven/Gradle allows to omit the upper bound).

Comment: I do not want to omit the upper version; rather I want to somehow replace the string `1.0+` with `[1.0)` before the assemble phase kicks in. Is it possible to do some string manipulation within `pom{}` and do this string conversion?

Comment: I tried using `[1.0)` in my gradle build and got error `Could not find com.demo.myapp:my-utils:[1.0)`.

Comment: Rewriting the POM will take a lot more effort (especially if it also has to work for versions other than `1.0+`), but should be possible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I do not want to omit the upper version", since this is exactly what `[1.0)` is doing. However, I think it needs to be `[1.0,)`.

Comment: Thank you Peter, the notation `[1.0,)` solved my issue. It is working with both Maven and Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

As per Peter Niederwieser, I should use notation `[1.0,)` as the version. This notation is understood by both Maven and Gradle.

```
ext {
       my_utils_version = "[1.0,)"
    }

    dependencies {
      compile "com.demo.myapp:my-utils:${my_utils_version}"
    }
```

This solved my problem. Since Peter did not reply this suggestion as an answer, I am doing that. So, the actual answer was given by Peter; not me :)

Thank you Peter for the help. It helped me saving a lot of time and got rid of another priority-1 issue in my application.